# 404 not found on Get Request

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im trying to build a Spring Boot application and one part of it is I need to get the total salary from an SQL database based on what department it is e.g. HR. When I do the get request in postman I get 404 not found where as for HR it's meant to return a value of 55000. Any help is greatly appreciated

Repository class

```
package com.example.demo.repositories;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.models.Department;
import com.example.demo.models.Employee;

public interface DepartmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Department, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "select sum(salary) from employee e inner join department d on e.id = d.id where did=?", nativeQuery = true)
    public void findSalaryByDept(String dept);

}
```

Service class

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.models.Department;
import com.example.demo.repositories.DepartmentRepository;

@Service
public class DepartmentService {
    @Autowired
    DepartmentRepository dr;
    

    public Iterable<Department> findAll() {
        return dr.findAll();
    }


    public void updateDepartment(Integer did, @Valid Department dept) {
        Optional<Department> deptDetails = dr.findById(did);
        
    }
    
    public void getDeptSalaryTotal(String did) {
        dr.findSalaryByDept(did);
    }
    
    
    

}
```

Controller class

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.demo.models.Department;
import com.example.demo.services.DepartmentService;

@RestController
@Validated
public class DepartmentController {
    @Autowired
    DepartmentService ds;
    

    @GetMapping(value = "/api/departments")
    public Iterable<DepartmentSummaryDto> getDepartments(){
        Iterable<Department> all = ds.findAll();
        List<DepartmentSummaryDto> summaries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Department dept : all) {
            summaries.add(new DepartmentSummaryDto(dept));
        }
        return summaries;
    }
    
    /*@PutMapping(value = "/api/departments/{did}")
    public void updateDepartment(@PathVariable(value="did") Integer did, @Valid @RequestBody Department dept){
        ds.updateDepartment();
    */
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/departments/{did}")
    public void getDeptSalaryTotal(@PathVariable(value="did") String did, @Valid @RequestBody Department dept) {
        ds.getDeptSalaryTotal(did);
    }
    

}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/import
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Adal135792!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=off
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
```

[image: SQL values]

[image]

Comment: please share a screenshot from Postman with the request and your project structure

Comment: Your uri in your code is `/api/departments` but you are calling this uri `/api/departments/hr`

Answer (score 1):

The URI registered as @GetMapping is `/api/departments/**`, **but the PostMan request is sending a request in the form** `/api/department/**`.
If you add "s" to the POSTMAN request, it will work properly.